# custom field values not coming in global search results

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, global-search

I have one custom object A with allow search enable. I have one custom field B for custom object A. I have one record of A with value of B as 1,212,212. i have added custom field B in search layout >search results. When i give 1,212,212 in global search it is not returning me any result but there is one record with B = 1,212,212.

How to add custom field to make it global search enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from the input (1,212,212) that custom field B is a number datatype and that is why the global search isn't returning the record. Adding field in search layout > search results determine the fields that are displayed on search results columns and doesn't affect the fields that are actually searched. Please refer [searchable fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_custom_object.htm&type=0) to have a look at searchable fields and types. If this is your main requirement and field isn't deployed yet, then edit the field datatype from number to text to make it as a searchable field. (FYI, changing already deployed field datatype with values might cause data loss)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below link which shows which objects can be searched and what can be searched as part of global fields.Number fields cannot be included in global search

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_cex.htm&language=en_US&type=0
[image]